# Issue with uploading .csv file with my provider

Tags: php, file, file-upload, csv

Hey guys so since switching from Winhost to Media Temple my .csv uploader has no been working.  I am running a totally dedicated server and it is all self managed and when I check the system error_logs.file I get:

```
[Sat Mar 30 04:47:53 2013] [warn] [client ip] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: seterror in mysite/getAccountsCSV.php on line 40, referer: mysite/memberinterface.php
[Sat Mar 30 04:47:53 2013] [warn] [client ip] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: csvfile in mysite/getAccountsCSV.php on line 42, referer: mysite/memberinterface.php
[Sat Mar 30 04:47:53 2013] [warn] [client ip] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in mysite/getAccountsCSV.php on line 44, referer: mysite/memberinterface.php
[Sat Mar 30 04:47:53 2013] [warn] [client ip] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in mysite/getAccountsCSV.php on line 46, referer: mysite/memberinterface.php
[Sat Mar 30 04:47:53 2013] [warn] [client ip] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in mysite/getAccountsCSV.php on line 48, referer: mysite/memberinterface.php
[Sat Mar 30 04:47:53 2013] [warn] [client ip] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in mysite/getAccountsCSV.php on line 48, referer: mysite/memberinterface.php
[Sat Mar 30 04:47:53 2013] [warn] [client ip] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in mysite/getAccountsCSV.php on line 50, referer: ./memberinterface.php
and it keeps going....
```

Heres my code:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['csvfile']['error'] ) )
    {

        $seterror = 1;
        returnBack();

    } 
    if (empty($_POST['firstname'])){

        $seterror =1;
        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['lastname'])){
        $seterrro =1;

        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['email'])){
        $seterror =1;

        returnBack();
    }
    if ($seterror != 1){

    $file = $_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name']; 
    var_dump($file);
    $handle = fopen($file , "r");

    $fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",");

    $fileop=array_map("strtoupper",array_map("trim",$fileop));

    $firstname_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST["firstname"]),$fileop);
    if ($firstname_index===false){
        returnBack();
    }
    $lastname_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST['lastname']),$fileop);
    if ($lastname_index===false){

        returnBack();
    }
    $email_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST['email']),$fileop);
    if ($email_index===false){

        returnBack();
    }
        //open file and store values
        while (($fileop=fgetcsv($handle)) !== false)
        {

            $fileop=array_map("trim",$fileop);
            $firstname[$j] = $fileop[$firstname_index];
            if (empty($firstname[$j])){ 
            exit;
            returnBackfile();

            }

            $lastname[$j] = $fileop[$lastname_index];
                if (empty($lastname[$j])){
                    exit;
            returnBackfile();

            }
            $email[$j] = $fileop[$email_index];
                if (empty($email[$j])){
            exit;
            returnBackfile();


            }
            $j++;
        }

        print_r($firstname);


    }
```

I have a form that is sent from a jquery ui-dialog div.....the user can upload file and info and is sent to here.  Please if you have any idea what I can do to fix this I would appreciate it!  I don't know if its a server issue like some settings that need to be changed or what?

EDIT:

Here is the top of the file before the if(!empty($_FIL.....

```
$setereror = 0;
$j = 0;
function returnBack(){

    header("Location:../memberinterface.php?getmsg=15");
    exit;

}
function returnBackfile(){

    header("Location:../memberinterface.php?getmsg=16");
    exit;

}
```

Comment: First, define `$seterror` variable before first `if`

Comment: And could you please give output of `var_dump($_FILES)`?

Comment: NULL..and I did set it

Comment: Then, contact your hosting provider. Probably, there is a problem in web-server configuration.

Comment: If you did set a default value for $seterror then you would not be getting the error "Undefined variable: seterror", so with all due respect, you obviously have not set it before you try reading it. Next thing to say is that there is obviously no file being received from a <input type="file" name="csvfile"> tag. If you are setting a default value for $seterror, please show us where you are doing so.

Comment: I am putting it on the top of the file $seterror = 0

Comment: Any idea what the problem might be in the web configuring?

Comment: So if you read what you have written, you are doing "$setereror = 0;" and thus you are NOT doing "$seterror = 0;"

Comment: @CaptainPayalytic, Sorry that was a miss spell, no it is correct and that is not the issue, the issue is that the file is not even being sent over in the first place.

Comment: I checked my HTML and file and it is all orrect....everything was working perfect on my other server now it wont upload :\